# complicated mysql table design choices

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am designing a rather complex database and am struggling with choices on one aspect.
Members can upload Videos, photos and stories, some free, some other members will pay for. The photographs need to be able to be grouped into sets with a name.

I have already decided to add to the members database columns representing "number of free photo sets", "number of paid photo sets"; same for the videos and stories.

The decision I am struggling with is with the storing of the set names, numbers in each set and type of set.

Please bear in mind, that if a set of photos has 6 in it, I will be need to show the relevant 6. Same for videos etc.

Files will be saved with coded titles - free photo, userid 2, set 3, picture 4 would be saved as FP020304.jpg (purely an example only) which is how I will know which ones to recall.

Choice 1 : One extra table for each member with the following columns (representative):

example entries being:

```
SET-ID | SetType    | SetName  | NumberInSet    
1      | freephotos | holiday  | 10
2      | paidphotos | birthday | 6
```

---

Choice 2: Same, but only one table for ALL members only with "MemberID" added to columns

Choice 3: One table for each type, for each member eg, one table for free photos, another for paid, etc.

Choice 4: same as 3 but with member id column added. (6 tables only)

Thinking so far:
Choice 3 seems easiest do do queries on, but I am not sure I like the idea of adding 6 tables for every new member.
Choice 4 seems the most logical as there will only ever be 6 tables, but extracting relevant info will be trickier.
Choices 1&2 result in less new tables per member, but also seems trickier getting results

I am not adverse to trickier solutions, however I just cant decide what would be best for this scenario - indeed, I am sure there are other ways I have yet to think of.

Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

(nb - first post - am hoping this comes out legible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choice 3 is horrible, erase it now.  I'd also advise against storing 'number in set' as a value in your database.  Everytime you insert a new photo, you would have to update the corresponding numberinset value.  Solution for it is not to store aggregate values in your database, use aggregates in your scripting to return this count instead.

I'd go with a 'members' or users table, a 'set' table that relates photo/video sets to your users (include free/paid as a column here).  From there create a photo/file table that relates photo's to the 'set' table.  Number of photo's/vidoe's in each set can be determined by

```
 select set_id , count(1) from mediatable group by set_id
```

This will give you that number in set value and you won't have to worry about updating a 'count' column like that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understand correctly then, go for choice 2 but without the aggregate value. I am curious though, I know we can count values, but being that with my site, that sets will never be changed after initial setup, is there any significant disadvantage to storing them? (apart from being suspected of lazy programming...lol)

Comment: Yes, I guess it is choice 2 ;)    If they never change...I don't think there is any direct disadvantage really (outside of enforcing the 'no change to the count' condition...it'll be more challenging to go back later on)...downside to lazy coding is in 3 years when the requirements change, not now.  Nor is it that difficult to write a script that would update all the count fields with the real count from the tables if you suspect they are no longer accurate in the future.  There's usually hundreds of ways to model your DB, it's a matter of choosing which options best meets requirments.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make new tables for each user, you just want one.  Also I would not name files with a coded title this makes it easy for bots or other users to incrementally go though the files if they know the scheme instead just save the path to the file and use a randomly generated name or hash.  Remember to set up `Foreign Keys` and `Indexes` to speed the `JOINS` and any searching you will do.

SetTypeTBL - `SetTypeID, SetTypeName`

SetTBL - `SetID, SetTypeID, MemberID, SetName`

MediaTypeTBL - `MediaTypeID, MediaTypeName`

MediaTBL - `MediaID, MediaTypeID, SetID, MemberID, MediaName, MediaFilePath`

Comment: Thanks for this. I have read v little about foreign keys, but from  what I have just read about them, they do seem to be appropriate for this kind of structure. Am going to go with the one extra table solution as mentioned in other answer too.